# Apache restart requires many times

Tags: apache

I m facing a problem related to apache as i have to start it so many times i m getting a error in magento please help. My var/log/httpd/error_log file shows below errors:

```
[Sat Aug 17 04:58:20.398508 2013] [core:notice] [pid 13152] AH00052: child pid 13633 exit signal Bus error (7)
[Sat Aug 17 04:59:08.588649 2013] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 13152] AH00170: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
[Sat Aug 17 04:59:08.988421 2013] [suexec:notice] [pid 13734] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Sat Aug 17 04:59:09.000312 2013] [ssl:notice] [pid 13734] AH01886: SSL FIPS mode disabled
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 2001:4801:7817:72:ae8d:c5a8:ff10:c59. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Sat Aug 17 04:59:09.163707 2013] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 13734] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sat Aug 17 04:59:10.001051 2013] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 13734] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Sat Aug 17 04:59:10.001272 2013] [ssl:notice] [pid 13734] AH01886: SSL FIPS mode disabled
Failed loading /usr/local/ioncube/ioncube_loader_lin_5.4.so:  /usr/local/ioncube/ioncube_loader_lin_5.4.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[Sat Aug 17 04:59:10.245942 2013] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 13734] AH00163: Apache/2.4.4 (Fedora) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips PHP/5.4.13 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Aug 17 04:59:10.246024 2013] [core:notice] [pid 13734] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
```

Comment: You will have to tell us what error you actually get. How do you expect people to help otherwise?

Comment: i m getting this error code in magento :  There has been an error processing your request

Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

Error log record number: 1229408047402

Comment: You should add such details to the question above by editing it. This is valuable information, keep to in one place, don't spread it all over the page. Does Magenta offer any means to see what is contained in that log record?

Comment: You should definately try to find out which action produces the error. Is it reproduceable? Does it happen on all requests? or just when opening a specific object/page?

Comment: yes, this issue occurs on all requests means on all pages.But FYI it happens after browsing 2 to 3 pages on site mean after approx 1 min.and i'm not able to find out why?

Answer (score 0):

That's a tricky one.  This:

```
child pid 13633 exit signal Bus error (7)
```

means it's dying somewhere - most likely (although not guaranteed) in the PHP code.

I would suggest:

1) Make sure that that is actually the error that is occurring when the Apache daemon dies.  I.e. do whatever you do that stops Apache and look in the log and see that that's the correct error.

2) If it is, enable XDebug on your Apache server and find out what line it's dying on.  (XDebug http://xdebug.org/ can take a little work to set up but it's a good tool to determine where in PHP your stuff dies ). If not, post what the last error(s) is/are.

nb. Magento is not noted for being a simple and easy to debug code base, I stopped using it for that reason (not because it was dying, because it is fat and complex).  Just my two cents.

Comment: thanks everyone, This issue was related to disk space,now it's solved.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was related to disk space,now it's solved.